# split url from textarea in php

Tags: php, url, split, textarea

I don't have much knowledge about regular expression. I found this code to detect link or you can say to insert link that is written in textarea

```
$url = 'this is just a link http://stackoverflow.com/ to test';
$text = preg_replace("
  #((http|https|ftp)://(\S*?\.\S*?))(\s|\;|\)|\]|\[|\{|\}|,|\"|'|:|\<|$|\.\s)#ie",
  "'<a href=\"$1\" target=\"_blank\">$3</a>$4'",
  $url
);
echo $text;
```

output:
this is just a link [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com) to test

But i need to separate the link into a variable from that text area. For example variable 
$var = http://stackoverflow.com  so that i can work with the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try in this way:

```
$text = 'this is just a link http://stackoverflow.com/ to test';
$regex = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
if(preg_match($regex, $text, $url)) { // $url is now the array of urls
  // here you should check $url content and length
  echo $url[0]; // the first one in this case
}
else {
  // no urls found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in two steps :

- capture URL's with preg_match or preg_match_all, specifying &$matches parameter
- replace URL's by your  tag via str_replace, looping on matches

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pre_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) if you want to capture each match and manipulate further before replace, or save it elsewhere. You can also just store that regex and do a match later. I would use the former, since you may have more than one link in the string and it would be cleaner than running your own for loop over the matches.